# How to prevent grep from printing a trailing newline?

Tags: linux, grep, newline

I am using `grep` to produce output that will be parsed by another program.

However, that program expects output only to be numeric or zero-bytes.

Now `grep` outputs a newline character after its output.  I've checked the `-Z` option but it doesn't seem to work as I'm using grep for counting (`-c`).

I am executing in `sh`, not `bash`. So nesting it into `echo -n "$(grep -c pattern)"` doesn't work either.

How can I get rid off the trailing newline?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can pipe it through `tr` and translate the `\n` to a `\0` character:

```
tr '\n' '\0'
```

Comment: Is not valid, by example: `echo -n 'x' | md5sum` is not same results using `echo 'x' | grep 'x' |  tr '\n' '\0' | md5sum`.

Answer (score 48):

Use [`tr -d`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/tr/) to delete characters in a string:

```
$ grep -c ' ' /etc/passwd | tr -d '\n'
69$ grep -c ' ' /etc/passwd | tr -d '\n' | xxd 
0000000: 3639                                     69
$
```

Comment: Without tr gdb shows `4\nj\000\000`, with tr it shows `4\346j\000\000` as the value of what it gets back from the command line. 4 is the counted number which I want.

Comment: Are you sure that `grep` is producing those characters after the number?

Answer (score 15):

I know this is old, and tr works just as well, but I happened across this question and noticed OP stated:
*I am executing in sh, not bash. So nesting it into echo -n "$(grep -c pattern)" doesn't work either.*

This isn't grep or sh so much as how echo is being used. For future visitors, the only reason this didn't work is due to the double quotes around the substituted command. The following does, in fact, work even using sh.

```
echo -n $(grep -c pattern)
```

Examples:

```
$ ls /dev/sd? #example of formatted output
/dev/sda  /dev/sdc  /dev/sde  /dev/sdg  /dev/sdi  /dev/sdk
/dev/sdb  /dev/sdd  /dev/sdf  /dev/sdh  /dev/sdj

$ echo $(ls /dev/sd?) #without -n, appends \n only at the end
/dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg /dev/sdh /dev/sdi /dev/sdj /dev/sdk

$ echo -n $(ls /dev/sd?) #with -n, does not append the \n, but still strips the line breaks from the string
/dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg /dev/sdh /dev/sdi /dev/sdj /dev/sdk

$ echo -n "$(ls /dev/sd?)" #output when double quotes are used
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
/dev/sdc
/dev/sdd
/dev/sde
/dev/sdf
/dev/sdg
/dev/sdh
/dev/sdi
/dev/sdj
/dev/sdk
```