# Docker compose failed while building Django app because of "grep -v" with trailing \r

Tags: django, bash, docker, debian

I'm trying to compose up a docker-compose file and there is one step where I ran `grep -v '^#' .env` to get all the uncommented lines from `.env` file to set environment variables.

In the `.env` file, it looks like this

`DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql`

However, after running `grep -v '^#' .env` and I check the environment, variable `DB_ENGINE` has value of `"django.db.backends.postgresql\r"` (notice the trailing `\r` there).

How can I overcome this? I've been doing this for a long time and it has never happened before.

Comment: One of your files probably has DOS/Windows-style line endings. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings), and especially the "Solutions" section of the top answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without trying a dos2unix on all your files, you could simply remove any `\`r from your grep result, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7249788/6309), with:

```
grep -v '^#' .env| tr -d '\r'
```